# Pass dapper class to postgres stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_participant(j json)
LANGUAGE plpgsql    
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO participant (procedure_id,lot_id)SELECT procedure_id,lot_id  FROM json_populate_record(null::participant, j);
    COMMIT;
END;
$$;
```

And a class:

```
    public class Participant : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Procedure_id{ get; set; }
        public int Lot_id { get; set; }      
    }
```

I'm trying the following:

```
        public void Add(Participant item)
        {
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                dbConnection.Execute("insert_participant", item, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
        }
```

But it fails and tells that there is no stored procedure with these paremeters.

What kind of parameter should I define when creating stored procedure in order for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper is expecting to send parameters which match to the declared properties on the type - so in this case it is going to want to send `Lot_id` and `Procedure_id`. It *looks* like you want to send the entire object as JSON instead, in which case you probably want:

```cs
var json = YourChoiceOfJsonSerializeAPI(item);
// possibly: var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
dbConnection.Execute("insert_participant", new { json },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

This now has one member called `json`, so one parameter named `json` will be added.

Comment: so there is no way to avoid serialization?

Comment: @NickFarsi You can if you rewire the stored procedure to not use json.

Comment: but that's the gist of the original question! What should I use instead of json as a parameter when declaring the procedure?

Comment: @NickFarsi if you don't want to serialize, then have parameters for each property that you want to send; I'm not going to obsess about the syntax (I'm mostly SQL Server), but I'd expect (again, using SQL Server syntax) `@id int, @name nvarchar(200), @dob datetime, ...` etc; I can't tell you what you need in your case without knowing what `BaseEntity` has, plus... again, syntactical differences, but presumably something like `@Procedure_id int, @Lot_id int` ?